# babel.config.js not loaded if cli-plugin-babel is installed from a package's dependencies

Tags: javascript, babeljs, vue-cli

In my team, all dependencies are placed in a separate package's dependencies (eg. packageA). When I install this packageA in a project, all dependencies like vue and vue-cli will be installed too. Here is the problem. The babel.config.js is not loaded. I put a console.log at the first line in this file, but it doesn't print anything when i start the project or run vue inspect.

However, when I place `"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0"` in project's package.json's dependencies field instead of in packageA's. Console.log works which means babel.config.js is loaded.

What happed here? If I want the babel.config.js to be loaded in the first case, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this......
[image: vue-cli-doc]

Vue Cli invoke plugins by searching dependencies in your project's package.json by default.